# How can I add multiple maintainers to a Chef Cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra

It sounds like this is a very valid use case (in the real world more than one ppl undertake the maintenance works), so I was wondering if there's something I'm missing with regards to the `metadata.rb` options.

The [docs](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html) state:

```
maintainer

The name of the person responsible for maintaining a cookbook, either an individual or an organization.

For example:

maintainer 'Adam Jacob'

`maintainer_email`

The email address for the person responsible for maintaining a cookbook. Only one email can be listed here, so if this needs to be forwarded to multiple people consider using an email address that is already setup for mail forwarding.

For example:

maintainer_email 'adam@example.com'
```

The above seems to be hinting that Chef only accepts one maintainer per cookbook... ?

Anyone ever seen it with more than one / know how it can be done?
(e.g. multiple `maintainer` lines)?

Comment: Just drop a `MAINTAINERS.md` in the cookbook repo. See this cookbook for an example. https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/users. FWIW, that's just an informative line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific way to do it. You could make the two strings (name and email) be comma-separated lists or whatever you want. Those fields are only for humans so what goes in them doesn't really matter to Chef other than they have to be strings. Probably wouldn't hurt to let them be arrays but also not really much to gain as, again, the only tool that uses that field is Supermarket's display.

Answer (score 1):

While creating cookbook locally you can use the **command** :

chef generate cookbook test -C "maintainer1","maintainer2" -m "maintainer1","maintainer2"

**metadata.rb** :

name 'test' 
maintainer 'maintainer1,maintainer2' 
maintainer_email 'maintainer1,maintainer2' 
license 'all_rights' 
description 'Installs/Configures test' 
long_description 'Installs/Configures test' 
version '0.1.0'